# Terraform azurerm_linux_web_app dynamic ip_restriction

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

i'm trying to create several applications in one go and i can successfully do it with count = length(var.webapp_name) but the problem that i'm facing is that some of the apps are required to communicate with each other and i need to whitelist outbound_ip_addresses on each app

the code that i use which is causing issues is the following:

```
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "API" {
      depends_on = [azurerm_subnet.subnet]
  count = length(var.webapp_name)

  name                  = lower("${var.customer4letter}-${var.env3letter}-${var.locationid3letter}-${var.servicetype}-${element(var.webapp_name, count.index)}")
  location              = var.location //West US 2
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  service_plan_id       = azurerm_service_plan.api-farm.id
  https_only            = "true"

  app_settings = {
        "WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER" = "True"
    }

  identity {
    type         = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  site_config {
    ftps_state  = "FtpsOnly"
    websockets_enabled = "false"
    use_32_bit_worker = "false"  
    always_on = "true"

    application_stack {
      dotnet_version   = "6.0"
    }
dynamic "ip_restriction"  {
      for_each = local.ip_address_list3
      content{
      action                    = "Allow"
      name = ip_restriction.value["name"]
      service_tag = ip_restriction.value["service_tag"]
      priority = ip_restriction.value["prior"]
  } }
  dynamic "ip_restriction" {
    for_each = azurerm_linux_web_app.API[0].outbound_ip_addresses
      content {
        ip_address  = cidrhost(ip_restriction.value,0)
      }  }  }   }
```

Local and variables set are

```
variable "webapp_name" {
    default = [ "app1", "app2", "app3" ]
}


locals {
ip_address_list3 = [
            {
                 service_tag               = "AppService"
                 prior : "102",
                 name = "VirtualNetwork"
            }
            ]
}
```

the error that i have is the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**I Tried to reproduce the same in my environment to azure web app with outbound IP using Terraform:**

**Terraform Code:**

```
provider  "azurerm"  {
features  {}
}
locals  {
resource_group_name = "test-rg"
location = "East US"
app_name_prefix = "venkatdemoapp"
}
resource  "azurerm_resource_group"  "test-rg"  {
name = local.resource_group_name
location = local.location
}

# Create multiple web apps

resource  "azurerm_app_service_plan"  "test_plan"  {
count = 2
name = "${local.app_name_prefix}-plan-${count.index}"
location = local.location
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg.name
sku  {
tier = "Basic"
size = "B1"
}
}
resource  "azurerm_app_service"  "thejawebapp"  {
count = 2
name = "${local.app_name_prefix}-${count.index}"
location = local.location
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg.name
app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.test_plan[count.index].id
}

# Restrict access to each web app
resource  "azurerm_network_security_group"  "test_nsg"  {
count = 2
name = "${local.app_name_prefix}-nsg-${count.index}"
location = local.location
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg.name
security_rule  {
name = "Allow_HTTP_Traffic"
priority = 100
direction = "Inbound"
access = "Allow"
protocol = "Tcp"
source_port_range = "*"
destination_port_range = "80"

source_address_prefix = "*"
destination_address_prefix = "*"
}
  security_rule  {
name = "Deny_All_Traffic"
priority = 200
direction = "Inbound"
access = "Deny"
protocol = "*"
source_port_range = "*"
destination_port_range = "*"
source_address_prefix = "*"
destination_address_prefix = "*"
}
}

# Associate each web app with its NSG.

resource  "azurerm_network_interface"  "test_nic"  {
count = 2
name = "${local.app_name_prefix}-nic-${count.index}"
location = local.location
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg.name
ip_configuration  {
name = "${local.app_name_prefix}-ipconfig-${count.index}"
    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.test_subnet.id
private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    }
    }
resource  "azurerm_subnet"  "test_subnet"  {
    name = "${local.app_name_prefix}-subnet"
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg.name
virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.test_vnet.name
address_prefixes = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
    }
  resource  "azurerm_virtual_network"  "test_vnet"  {

name = "${local.app_name_prefix}-vnet"

location = local.location
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg.name    address_space = ["10.0.0.0/16"]

}
```

**Terraform Apply:**

[image]

Once ran the above code resources are created automatically with restriction.

[image]

**NSG Rule:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for responding on my question but this doesnt fix the problem that i have because you are creating two service farm and i use only one. which means i need to have IP Address rules based on the outbound ip address range from each App service

Comment: if you want to create only one appservice change the count to 1 in code and check the result and change rule type to Outbound.

Comment: i did used your template and it is creating app services but the ip restriction for each app service is not enabled. on the other hand you are creating NGS to allow port 80. WHat i need here is to have whitelist on top of each APP services which is done by the ip_restriction. To clarify i need to use all Outbound ip address range from the APP Service to allow Inbound traffic based on this ip address.

Comment: Specifies the IP address in site config section that will be allowed inbound traffic to the App Service. 

resource "azurerm_app_service" "thejawebapp" {
  name                = "thejawebapp-app-service"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test-rg.name

  site_config {
    ip_restriction {
      ip_address = "App Service IP"
    }
  }
}

Comment: I Already did that even with dynamic ip restriction but i want to find a way to allow my apps to communicate between each other without running again terraform apply and adding the ip range from apps

Comment: Create an NSG for each Azure web app and add inbound rules to allow traffic from the IP range of the other Azure  web apps.

Associate the NSGs with the virtual networks that the Azure web apps are connected to.
Follow my code to Associate NSG for each web app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251754/discussion-between-venkatv-and-igor).